# Standard equation to steer left or right while advancing a differential whee

Tags: arduino

I am writing a code in Arduino IDE for NodeMCU Board to control a differential drive 2 wheeled robot.

I am able to steer only one direction for some reason and the steering response time is a little awkward.

Is there perhaps a better strategy for the code that I am using?`

```
if(Y > 130 && X < 126)   //Steer Left
  {
    motorA = Y;
    motorB = Y;
    Steer = X / maximo;

    motorA = map(motorA, 126, 0, 450,maximo);
    analogWrite(5, motorA * (1 + Steer));
    digitalWrite(0,LOW);
   motorB = map(motorB, 126, 0, 450,maximo);
    analogWrite(4, motorB * (1 - Steer));
    digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
  }

   if(Y > 130 && X > 130)   //Steer Right
  {
    motorA = Y;
    motorB = Y;
    Steer = X / maximo;

    motorA = map(motorA, 130,255 , 450,maximo);
    analogWrite(5, motorA * (1 - Steer));
    digitalWrite(0,LOW);
    motorB = map(motorB, 130,255 , 450,maximo);
    analogWrite(4, motorB * (1 + Steer));
    digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!`

Comment: Did your previous question get an acceptable answer?

Comment: You left out the rest of the code and now one has to wonder what things like "maximo" are

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Arduino to power both motors? I found that only one got full power, and the second motor in the circuit ran significantly slower. I found switching to an Arduino motor shield with a separate power source just for the motors did the trick.

Comment: I am actually using a nodemcu controller with the Arduino IDE Software to program it. There is a motor adapter board made for it but I think it still uses an LM293 if Im not mistaken.